Sign with xcode build on CI/Github actions with fastlane results in signing error regarding SPM frameworks
I am manually on GitHub action trying to sign my iOS app.
I am using fastlane (partially) to help me. I do not want to use match as I intend to reuse the script between customers so I cannot use a shared git-repo.
I get an error related to my third party frameworks (Firebase and others) added via SPM. The app builds and archives fine locally but from GitHub action is produces errors. This is how the archive is performed (via fastlane on GitHub action):
I've tried various combinations of arguments for xcode build but without success.
This is my lane in fastlane. It's not the entire code but gives a overview of how I perform it:
  lane :archive_pixelmost do |options|
    providedProjectTeamId = options[:projectTeamId]
    bundle_id = ENV['BUNDLE_ID']

    appPath = "../buildTarget/build.appmostapp"

    if providedProjectTeamId.nil?
      iOSProjectTeamId = sh("jq '.buildIOSProjectTeamId' '#{appPath}/app.json' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '\\' | tr -d '\"'").strip
    else
      iOSProjectTeamId = providedProjectTeamId
    end

    UI.user_error!("iOS Project Team ID not found") if iOSProjectTeamId.nil? || iOSProjectTeamId.empty?

    # Fetch certificates and provisioning profiles
    certificates_and_profiles = fetch_certificates_and_profiles

    cert_id = certificates_and_profiles[:cert_id]
    provisioning_profile_path = certificates_and_profiles[:profile_path]
    provisioning_profile_specifier = File.basename(provisioning_profile_path).split('.').first
    profile_name = certificates_and_profiles[:profile_name]
    cert_name = certificates_and_profiles[:cert_name]

    UI.message("cert_id: #{cert_id}, profile_name: #{profile_name} provisioning_profile_specifier: #{provisioning_profile_specifier}, iOSProjectTeamId: #{iOSProjectTeamId} cert_name: #{cert_name}")

    # Update the project team for all targets
    update_project_team(
      path: "./projectx.xcodeproj",
      targets: buildTargetNames + ["BuildTarget_AppClip"],
      teamid: iOSProjectTeamId
    )

     keychain_password = "temporary_password"
     keychain_path = "#{ENV['RUNNER_TEMP']}/app-signing.keychain-db"

     # Rensa och lås upp keychain före byggningen
     sh "security list-keychains -s #{keychain_path} ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
     sh "security default-keychain -s #{keychain_path}"
     sh "security unlock-keychain -p #{keychain_password} #{keychain_path}"

     export_options_path = "../projectx/Supporting files/BuildTarget/exportOptions.plist"

     unless File.exist?(export_options_path)
       UI.user_error!("exportOptions.plist filen finns inte på sökvägen: #{export_options_path}")
     end

     export_options = Plist.parse_xml(export_options_path)
     if export_options.nil?
       UI.user_error!("Kunde inte läsa in exportOptions.plist som en Hash. Kontrollera att filen är en giltig plist.")
     end

     UI.message("bundle_id: #{bundle_id} profile_name: #{profile_name}")
     export_options['teamID'] = iOSProjectTeamId
     export_options['provisioningProfiles'] = { bundle_id => profile_name }

     File.open(export_options_path, 'w') { |f| f.write(export_options.to_plist) }

     sh "xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace '../projectx.xcworkspace' -scheme 'BuildTarget'"

     sh "xcodebuild clean -workspace '../projectx.xcworkspace' -scheme 'BuildTarget' -configuration Release"

     disable_automatic_code_signing(
       path: "./projectx.xcodeproj",
       use_automatic_signing: false,
       targets: ["BuildTarget"]
     )

     sh "xcodebuild archive -scheme 'BuildTarget' -workspace '../projectx.xcworkspace' -configuration Release -archivePath ../build/BuildTarget.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM='#{iOSProjectTeamId}' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='#{cert_name}' PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='#{profile_name}' -allowProvisioningUpdates ARCHS='arm64' VALID_ARCHS='arm64' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=Yes CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=Yes"

   end


end

Here is a resolved command running:
xcodebuild archive -scheme BuildTarget -workspace ../projectx.xcworkspace -configuration Release -archivePath ../build/BuildTarget.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=W3KA9856B7 "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=Apple Distribution: Appfrilans AB (W3KA9856B7)" "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299" -allowProvisioningUpdates ARCHS=arm64 VALID_ARCHS=arm64 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=Yes CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=Yes

The error:
Exit status of command 'xcodebuild archive -scheme 'BuildTarget' -workspace '../projectx.xcworkspace' -configuration Release -archivePath ../build/BuildTarget.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM='W3KA9856B7' CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='Apple Distribution: Appfrilans AB (W3KA9856B7)' PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299' -allowProvisioningUpdates ARCHS='arm64' VALID_ARCHS='arm64' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=Yes CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=Yes' was 65 instead of 0.

/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectx-ajepocrionzredcbzdsapmxpgxgi/SourcePackages/checkouts/GoogleUtilities/Package.swift: error: GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Reachability does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Reachability does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Reachability' from project 'GoogleUtilities')
/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectx-ajepocrionzredcbzdsapmxpgxgi/SourcePackages/checkouts/ASN1Swift/Package.swift: error: ASN1Swift does not support provisioning profiles. ASN1Swift does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'ASN1Swift' from project 'ASN1Swift')
/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectx-ajepocrionzredcbzdsapmxpgxgi/SourcePackages/checkouts/GoogleUtilities/Package.swift: error: GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Environment does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Environment does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleUtilities_GoogleUtilities-Environment' from project 'GoogleUtilities')
/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/projectx-ajepocrionzredcbzdsapmxpgxgi/SourcePackages/checkouts/GoogleUtilities/Package.swift: error: GoogleUtilities-Reachability does not support provisioning profiles. GoogleUtilities-Reachability does not support provisioning profiles, but provisioning profile se.polartouch.reskollen AppStore 1720188299 has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor. (in target 'GoogleUtilities-Reachability' from project 'GoogleUtilities')

This error is repeated for all frameworks I'm using via SPM: Firebase_FirebaseAuth, FirebaseCore, nanopb_nanopb, FirebaseFirestoreTarget, FirebaseStorage et.c.
I've tried:

CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No, this works, but then uploading it to Testflight fails
Setting different PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER, to provisioning_profile_specifier, profile_name, "Automatic", remove it.
Removing disable_automatic_code_signing
Removing cert
Revving allowProvisioningUpdates
Removing all arguments

Edit 1:
I've been able to run the same command locally on my computer to speed up my iteration and testing abilities. I've manually created certificate and profile in developer.apple.com and imported them to my computer. However, If I disable manual code signing it seems that if I set something other than "Apple Development" I get this error:
error: Firebase_FirebaseCoreInternal has conflicting provisioning settings.
Firebase_FirebaseCoreInternal is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity Apple Distribution has been manually specified.
Set the code signing identity value to "Apple Development" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
(in target 'Firebase_FirebaseCoreInternal' from project 'Firebase')

However, if I do set it to "Apple Development" it does use the correct profile, but fails to match it with a (right) distribution cert, but instead chooses a development cert which lacks the profile...
error: Provisioning profile "Polartouch" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: Created via API (AFG4LX6NWZ)". (in target 'BuildTarget' from project 'projectx')


Finally got it working. For me the solution was to not include any arguments for Certificate nor Provisioning profiles in the xcodebuild command. Instead set these directly in the build targets setting.
So the resulting command would only be:
 sh "xcodebuild archive -scheme 'BuildTarget' -workspace '../projectx.xcworkspace' -configuration Release -archivePath ../build/BuildTarget.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM='#{iOSProjectTeamId}'"

And then I would use 'Xcodeproj' to set the Provisioning Profile Specifier in the target settings dynamically. Codesigning was set to "iOS Distribution" for the target.
